# Backwards key reloads previous page in React

Tags: reactjs

I have to following component:

```
import React from 'react';

const SearchInput = ({className, onChange}) => {
  const onTextInputChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    onChange(value);
  };

  return (
    <textarea
      className={className} onChange={onTextInputChange}>
    </textarea>
  )
};

export default SearchInput;
```

But after filling some text, and then deleting it, the previous page is reloaded. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Could you show your problem in https://jsfiddle.net or in https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: @Andrew the app is to complex for that. But I can say that in this case, of the textarea becoming empty, I can't event debug the function. it likes the textarea itself is redirecting to the previous page

Comment: i'm interested in `onChange` function and in previous page component.

Comment: Are you playing around with focus within your app? The backspace key will send you back in many browsers. If your element were to lose focus, then hitting backspace might have the same effect as hitting the Back button.

Answer (score 0):

Add [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in your function:

```
const SearchInput = ({className, onChange}) => {
  const onTextInputChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const value = e.target.value;
    onChange(value);
  };

  return (
    <textarea
      className={className} onChange={(e) => onTextInputChange}>      
    </textarea>
  )
};
```

Comment: @Chen could you try this, adding `e` on onChange attribute.

Comment: Tries now, well, only `(e) => onTextInputChange(e)` actually made the function call. And the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! apparently on the `onChange` from the parent component, I did a comparison between String and Array, it throws an exception that lead to the page reloading. 
Thanks @Andrew for directing me in this direction.

Comment: `preventDefault` was neccesary ?

Comment: I'm glad to help :)